# DNN: change name of property showing in PropertyEditorControl

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm build a new authentication provider for DNN and I'd like to know if there's any custom attribute that can be applied to the property settings object that is bound to the PropertyEditorControl so that its label shows a different name from the one used on property.

For instance, suppose my classe has a property named ServiceId. Instead of showing that name, I'd like the PropertyEditorControl to show the string "Serv. Identification".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this can be done through resource files with predefined entries for each property you're interested in changing the label...